# Access SSM Parameter store value in an aws amplify react js application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I have an amplify application built using React JS, I have a scenario for which I am manually storing API keys in my SSM parameter store in my AWS account. However, I want to retrieve/get those values(JSON object) based on a key from my React JS app (client side). So, I have installed the aws-sdk, the AWS JavaScript sdk, and using the below code snipped I am trying to access the ssms parameter store

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region:'us-east-1'});
const ssm = new AWS.SSM();


const getSecret = async (secretName) => {
  console.log(`Getting secret for ${secretName}`);
  const params = {
    Name: secretName, 
    WithDecryption: true
  };

  const result = await ssm.getParameter(params).promise();
  return result.Parameter.Value;
};

module.exports = {getSecret};
```

I am receiving this error on running my application and while accessing the store using the getSecret function.

> Unhandled Rejection (CredentialsError): Missing credentials in config,
> if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1

I believe that amplify configures the environment implicitly but since, the SSM Secrets manager is not supported yet by Amplify hence, I have to use the JS AWS SDK for this purpose. Can anyone help me spot the issue while configuring the service using AWS SDK? Or is there another or a better way to access parameter store from the client side?

Also, after surfing I have found a package named [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Is it okay to store aws credentials in such a way?

Comment: The issue is Your code is unable to find the credentials to connect to AWS services.  when you run from local machine its picked from .users/credentials file. And you shouldn't be storing the credentials in client side.

Comment: you may have to put the code to access parameter store on server side app and expose it via some endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I have the credentials in the shared windows path 'C:\Users\USER_NAME\.aws\config' but still I am getting this error. Any leads? Note: I have a custom profile name set not the default name.

Answer (score 2):

Your code to fetch `parameter store` keys/values shouldn't be at client side considering security implications. It should be done at server-side and functionality can be exposed over endpoint for client-side.

You can read the credentials programmatically something like below:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'profile name'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
```

Refrence:

1. [loading-node-credentials-shared](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html)
2. [global-config-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/global-config-object.html)

Comment: Yes, considering the security implications I have moved this logic to dynamodb where I am storing and retrieving the keys via crypto-js, a client side encrypt/decrypt library. Also, Utilizing GraphQL for that this purpose. Thanks for the answer anyways :)